# jQuery inline if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, if-statement, anonymous-function

I am using the following code to toggle the text of an `<a>` tag:

```
$(function() {
    $(".button-table-holder").click(function () {
        $('.tableHolder').slideToggle(500);
        return false;
    });

    var text = $('.button-table-holder').text();
    $('.button-table-holder').text(text == "Show full product specifications" ? "Hide" : "Show full product specifications");
});
```

The text seems to be stuck on *Show full product specifications* though... I would like it so that it changes whenever I click the link

Comment: Please share the html as well

Comment: Your code which changes the text should be in `click-handler`

Answer (score 0):

If you want that something happened on each click, then it should be included in the `click` function (in this case for *.button-table-holder*).

In the present shape, the last instruction is executed only once.

Answer (score 0):

Your code that changes text is not placed inside click listener. You should do something like:

```
$(".button-table-holder").click(function () {
    var text = $('.button-table-holder').text();
    $('.button-table-holder').text(text == "Show full product specifications" ? "Hide" : "Show full product specifications");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not place the two lines that adjust your text inside the click event handler, meaning they only run once (when the document is ready). Try this instead:

```
$(function() {
    $(".button-table-holder").click(function () {
        $('.tableHolder').slideToggle(500);
        var text = $('.button-table-holder').text();
        $('.button-table-holder').text(text == "Show full product specifications" ? "Hide" : "Show full product specifications");
        return false;
    });
});
```